# Euclidean distance between the unbiased covariance estimator and the true covariance

Tags: covariance, distance, euclidean

Let X be a n*p matrix whose p columns are sampled from a centred normal multivariate distribution with true covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and let $\Sigma_{n}$ be its unbiased sample covariance estimator for n observations, how can I find ${\mathbb{E}(||\Sigma_{n}-\Sigma||}_{2})$ ?